# Given $N$, find the largest $U=ab=cd$ with $a,b,c,d\leq N$

Tags: nt.number-theory

Recently I was thinking about this problem:

Consider only positive integers. Given $N$, find the largest $U$ which can be expressed as the product of two integers less than or equal to $N$, in at least two different ways.

It turns out that such $U$ must be of this form:

$U=p(q-1)\times q(p-1)=pq\times (p-1)(q-1)$

where $pq\leq N$. Let $n^2\leq N<(n+1)^2$. If $N=n^2$ or $N=n(n+1)$ or $N=n(n+2)$, it is easy to figure out that one of $p,q$ is $n$ and the other is $N/n$. The problem arises when

1) $n^2<N<n^2+n$;

2) $n^2+n<N<n^2+2n$.

I analyzed case 2). Let $\alpha=N-n^2-n$. It seems $p,q$ should be of this form: $n+1+k+j$ and $n-j$ with $k\geq 1$ and

$j=\lceil-\frac{k+1}{2}+\sqrt{kn+(\frac{k+1}{2})^2-\alpha}\rceil$

To find the optimal $k$, let $k=1$ and $j=\lceil -1+\sqrt{n+1-\alpha}\rceil$ and search if there is any $k,j$ with larger $pq$.

For example, when $N=435$, take $k=1$ we get $24*18$ but there is a better one, $k=3$ with $29*15$.

Anybody has thought about this problem before? Is there anything more we can do about it?

Comment: With these type of problems what one should usually try to do is fix $U$ and find $N$ based on $U$.

Comment: Do you mean $U$ is bounded above and find the upper estimate of $N$?

Comment: Yes. I do mean that. Thanks for clarifying.